# why i cannot get all number errors when importing data

Tags: drupal, import

i face errors data when import.
when i click download erros , i can't get all of them
for example erros = 4000, when i click download erros link i only got 500.
why are cannot i get all the number of errors?

i attahed for more detail.

[image]

thanks in advance

civicrm 4.411
drupal 7.32

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure how you got 500 Error because by default only 250 errors will be printed in civi. if you want the full list just go to CRM/Import/Parser.php file and change the const `MAX_ERRORS` value. This way you can get the full list. also do consider the `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`.

Comment: Thanks very much @coleman, 
as i said , got 500 erros just example ( it mean , why  i can't got all erros ) :).

its very help 
regards henro